# Jest fails: HTMLElement is not defined

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test my Typescript project with Jest. But it fails with following error:

```
 FAIL  tests/index.test.ts
 ● Test suite failed to run

  ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined

  > 1 | export class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement { }
      |                                      ^
    2 |
    3 | customElements.define("my-custom-element", MyCustomElement);
    4 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:1:38)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/index.test.ts:2:1)
```

This is my configuration:

dependencies in packages.json:

```
"@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
"@types/node": "^14.18.48",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
"typescript": "^5.0.4"
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceRoot": "src/",
    "outDir": "../src/js/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

jest.config.ts:

```
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testRegex: '/tests/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|tsx)$'
};

export default config;
```

src/index.ts:

```
export class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement { }

customElements.define("my-custom-element", MyCustomElement);
```

tests/index.test.ts:

```
import { describe, expect, test } from '@jest/globals';
import { MyCustomElement } from '../src/index';

describe('testing index file', () => {
  test('should compile', () => {
    var element: MyCustomElement = new MyCustomElement();
    expect(element).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Interestingly when removing `"dom"` from tsconfig.json the error changes, because Typescript can not compile `index.ts`.

Does this mean Jest doesn't use the libs from tsconfig.json? How do I get Jest to work properly?

Comment: The ["lib" config](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) doesn't actually make those names available, just declares what you expect to be already in the runtime environment. If you're testing code to run in a DOM environment you need e.g. JSDOM or an actual browser.